# Arrange indices of objects from an array based on a common object property's value into two separate arrays in respective order

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects where the property 'selectOrder' can have repeated value for only two objects, (scenario: one object is selected right after another with the same value). I need two separate arrays where I can find the indices of the objects that had matching value for the 'selectOrder' property in respective orders of indices of the new arrays.

Edit: If there isn't a repeated 'selectOrder', then the object's index gets repeated in both arrays.

```
let A = [
0: {id:343, name:'Apple', selectOrder:0},
1: {id:423, name:'Banana' selectOrder:2}
2: {id:234, name:'Cat', selectOrder:3},
3: {id:543, name:'Dog', selectOrder:1},
4: {id:432, name:'Elephant', selectOrder:1},
5: {id:545, name:'Father', selectOrder:0},
];
```

Desired Output:

```
Arr1=[0, 3, 1, 2]
Arr2=[5, 4, 1, 2]
```

Edit: Ideally, it should add the index of object with selectOrder:0 in Arr1 first and immediately after that looks for another objects with selectOrder:0 and adds it's index to  Arr2 and so on for other selectOrders.

Comment: Note that the code you've presented here is syntactically incorrect. Please use correct syntax for arrays (e.g., `[0, 3, 1, 2]` or `[5,4,1,2]`), rather than the object-like syntax the code is in now. If you are copying from the console, use `console.log(array, null, 2)` to get the best output.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, I've edited it according to your suggestion.

Comment: have you tried to write the code and need help with it? If so, post the code you tried and what went wrong. If not, you should try to come up with a solution first and then post what you tried here (and how it failed to do what you wanted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution I could think of,

```js
let A = [{
    id: 343,
    name: 'Apple',
    selectOrder: 0
  },
  {
    id: 423,
    name: 'Banana',
    selectOrder: 2
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    name: 'Cat',
    selectOrder: 3
  },
  {
    id: 543,
    name: 'Dog',
    selectOrder: 1
  },
  {
    id: 432,
    name: 'Elephant',
    selectOrder: 1
  },
  {
    id: 545,
    name: 'Father',
    selectOrder: 0
  },
];

const tracker = {};

A.forEach((el, i) => {
  if (!tracker[el.selectOrder]) {
    tracker[el.selectOrder] = {
      index1: i
    };
  } else {
    tracker[el.selectOrder].index2 = i;
  }
});

const Arr1 = [];
const Arr2 = [];

for (let selectOrder of Object.values(tracker)) {
  Arr1.push(selectOrder.index1);
  if (selectOrder.index2) {
    Arr2.push(selectOrder.index2);
  } else {
    Arr2.push(selectOrder.index1);
  }
}

console.log('Arr1: ', Arr1);
console.log('Arr2: ', Arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a subtle change in your data structure and output format. You can try this. If it does not work then you can contact with me.

```js
let A = [
    {i: 0, id:343, name:'Apple', selectOrder: 0},
    {i: 1, id:423, name:'Banana', selectOrder: 2},
    {i: 2, id:234, name:'Cat', selectOrder: 3},
    {i: 3, id:543, name:'Dog', selectOrder: 1},
    {i: 4, id:432, name:'Elephant', selectOrder: 1},
    {i: 5, id:545, name:'Father', selectOrder: 0},
];

// Sort by selectOrder
A.sort((a, b) => a.selectOrder - b.selectOrder);

let arr1 = [], arr2 = [];

A.forEach((item, i) => {
  if (!arr1.find((x, k) => k === item.selectOrder)) {
    arr1.push({[item.selectOrder]: item.i});
  } else if (!arr2.find((x, k) => k === item.selectOrder)) {
    arr2.push({[item.selectOrder]: item.i});
  }
});

// Push the extra values from arr1 into arr2
arr2 = [...arr2, ...arr1.slice(arr2.length)]

console.log(arr1, arr2);
```

**Note: The output format something like the previous one you've posted the first time.**

Comment: I actually need it as just values inside array instead of objects in an array. In the previous one I was just showing the indices of the array to make sure they correspond with the 'selectOrder''s value.